# How to remove space between elements in a CSS pagination?

Tags: css, pagination, space, jsfiddle

Unintended space appears between elements of a simple pagination. Check this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Daoist_Paradox/g5orz3kw/7/)

What's the reason behind this?

(This is the pagination below so the question can be posted.)

```
        <div class="pagination">
            <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
            <a href="#">1</a>
            <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <a href="#">4</a>
            <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: you mean the space between `a` tags?

Comment: yes. I can't seem to figure out how to eliminate that space. I tried fiddling with the code but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the following in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

```js
//from https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF
```

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
 <div class="pagination">
   <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
   <a href="#">1</a>
   <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
   <a href="#">3</a>
   <a href="#">4</a>
   <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually setting `<a>` elements like that already create the spaces. If you remove all CSS code, you will see that the spaces remain.
By adding your CSS, you effectively reduced the **proportional** difference between the highlighted spaces. Because, as you increase two adjacent objects by the same proportion (each of them X), and the space between increases in the same proportion (one X only), the only thing that decreases is their distance to each other in relation to their size.

**All I did was add a negative margin** on both sides of each `.pagination a` like so:

```
.pagination a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin: 0px -3px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

Note: Just add the margin line under your `.pagination a` and set the negative value for the horizontal margin that suits your needs.